# How could i get the complete list of puppet modules availabe from puppet repo

Tags: module, automation, puppet

I'm looking for a way to get the list of complete puppet modules from the puppet repo

Comment: Are you asking about [Puppet Forge](https://forge.puppet.com/)?  Otherwise, I'm not sure what you mean by "the puppet repo".

Comment: Yes the Puppet Forge ,i need the complete list of all their available modules in a text file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am aware, there is no direct way to get such a list.  I would consider [inquiring directly of Puppet, Inc.](https://puppet.com/contact/), as it's not out of the question that they would be willing to run a one-off special query for you.  I'm sure they would want to know what you want to do with the list, though.  And, of course, this is by no means a sure thing.

You could also use a bot to screen-scrape the multiple HTML pages of [the all-module list](https://forge.puppet.com/modules), and process the results to extract the list you want.  But that would be a lot more work than just asking.

Note well that the Forge contents are not static.  New modules are added regularly, and module versions are updated from time to time.  I'm uncertain about the policy for removals, but it seems that they generally do not remove modules, but rather deprecate them.  In any case, any list of the Forge contents would necessarily be a snapshot from a single point in time.

You should also understand that although the Forge itself is operated by Puppet, most of the modules are contributed and maintained by community members, if they are maintained at all.  There is also an unknown but probably large number of modules in use in the world that are not available from the Forge.  Thus, the list you are asking for cannot be construed as a list of official modules, nor as a list of all the modules there are.